# Python How to fill an array arr[i, j] within a for loop that calculates the values that will be put into i and j

Tags: python, arrays

This is a program that must compute the flow rate of salt water needed to achieve a certain density profile. The important variables I need to store are Q and t as they will then be used to tell my pump how fast to run in real time.

```
import numpy as np

for z in np.arange(0, 0.5, 0.01):

    Q = a + z    # where a is a predefined number
    t = b + z    # where b is a predefined number

    # here I would like to store Q and t in an array

    for something in arr[i, j]:
        i = t
        j = Q
```

Comment: This question needs some clarification. You have a 2D array `arr`. You calculated `Q` and `t`. This is done for every value `z` in np.arrange(...). What do you want that to look like. Is your goal to generate something like:
 [ [ Q,t ], [2nd_Q, 2nd_t ], ... ]? And what are you trying to do with this data? You say `do I use two for loops here or can I use one?`, but for what?

Comment: And are you sure a 2D array is what you need?

Comment: @rp.beltran : yes thats exactly what I need, [Q][t] then [2nd_Q][2nd_t] and so on. I believe an array is best but I'm a physicist and know little about programming. The reason for storing this data in memory is that it will be fed through a controller to my water pumps which will then adjust their speed to Q for every time t. Thanks for answering!

Comment: although thinking about it now, it would just have to be a 1D array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do the trick.

```
arr = []
for z in np.arange(0, 0.5, 0.01):

    Q = a + z
    t = b + z

    # here I would like to store Q and t in an array
    arr.append([t,Q])

for item in arr:
    i = item[0]
    j = item[1]
```

It creates a list called arr that stores lists of `[Q,t]` values.

Comment: `for item in arr:
        i = item[0]
        j = item[1]`

This does not do anything

Comment: Thats better if he needs to do calculations with them. If however they are immediately used like this, it makes more sense to put the calculations inside the loop.

Comment: I agree, but this is more a demo on how he can extract the data stored in `arr` (since he didn't provide details in his question about how he plans on using it)

Answer (score 0):

Multidimensional arrays are just arrays of arrays.

If `arr` is defined as the 2D array that looks like:

```
[ [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6] ]
```

`arr[0]` would return `[1,2]`

If you have an empty array, as in `arr = []` and you want to add a row to it, you can just append a new array. For example to generate the 2D array above, you could use the code:

```
arr = []
arr.append([1,2])
arr.append([3,4])
arr.append([5,6])
```

In the context of your problem, if you just need to add rows to your array to hold the two calculated values `Q` and `t` use:

```
import numpy as np

arr = []

for z in np.arange(0, 0.5, 0.01):

    Q = a + z # where a is a predefined number
    t = b + z # where b is a predefined number

    # here I would like to store Q and t in a 2D array
    arr.append([Q,t])

print arr
```

If however, you computations can be done inside the loop, then there is no need to instantiate any arrays at all.

```
import numpy as np

for z in np.arange(0, 0.5, 0.01):

    Q = a + z # where a is a predefined number
    t = b + z # where b is a predefined number

    # Do your calculations with Q ant t
    print Q + t # replace with your actual calculations
```

This is more efficient, uses less code, and is easier to design.

I hope that helps.

Comment: thats great thank you! I didn't know about the append function

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 2-d array without a Python loop using [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
#Constants
a = 3
b = 2
```

Make `z` a 2-d array

```
z = np.array((np.arange(0, 0.1, 0.01),np.arange(0, 0.1, 0.01)))

>>> print(z)
[[ 0.    0.01  0.02  0.03  0.04  0.05  0.06  0.07  0.08  0.09]
 [ 0.    0.01  0.02  0.03  0.04  0.05  0.06  0.07  0.08  0.09]]
>>>
```

Put the constants in a 1-d array

```
c = np.array((a,b))

>>> print(c)
[3 2]
>>> print(z.shape, z.T.shape, c.shape)
((2, 10), (10, 2), (2,))
>>>
```

Add the constants to z

```
qt = z.T + c

>>> print(qt)
[[ 3.    2.  ]
 [ 3.01  2.01]
 [ 3.02  2.02]
 [ 3.03  2.03]
 [ 3.04  2.04]
 [ 3.05  2.05]
 [ 3.06  2.06]
 [ 3.07  2.07]
 [ 3.08  2.08]
 [ 3.09  2.09]]
>>>

for thing in qt:
    print(thing)

>>> 
[ 3.  2.]
[ 3.01  2.01]
[ 3.02  2.02]
[ 3.03  2.03]
[ 3.04  2.04]
[ 3.05  2.05]
[ 3.06  2.06]
[ 3.07  2.07]
[ 3.08  2.08]
[ 3.09  2.09]
>>>
```

---

Another [numpy broadcasting](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/operations.html#broadcasting) link.  There are many other good explanations out *there*.